# dry run of worst case of quick sort

Tags: arrays, data-structures, quicksort

we know that in quick sort worst case is O(n^2)
i can solving the array of:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

when i put value of n in equation of worst case answer is 100 
but in dry run it can solve in 51 steps.
its a big difference what the reason of this

Comment: The main reason is selecting good pivot item. If you choose pivot from left or right side - it isn't good. If you select this item randomly - quick sort may work quickly.

Comment: no i can change the pivot 3 times but still ans is same

Comment: The worst case is if items are sorted and you choose pivot item from left or right side. In this case you will get n^2.

Comment: n^2 gives 100 ans means its solve in 100 steps but it can solve in 51 steps

Answer (score 2):

O(n^2) means that the complexity grows with the square of `n`, not that it is exactly `n^2`.

You need to check how the cost (`ans`) grows when `n` grows. Try putting 5, 10 and 20 items in the worst-case array and then you will see that `an`s does not grow proportionally (2x each time) to `n` but much faster.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to consider the definition of Big O when thinking about how it can be applied, in this case, to the worst case scenario in a quick sort algorithm. The Big O describes the asymptotic behavior of functions. When referring to an algorithm, the running time is bounded above by f(x) which is O(f(x)). What this means is that your algorithm cannot grow any faster than f(x). In your example, quick sort is bounded above by (n^2), therefore, it cannot grow any faster than n^2 as n gets arbitrarily large.

Being bounded above by n^2 does not necessarily mean the worst case takes exactly n^2 steps. It is also bounded above by n^4, n^100, n^n. All this means is that quick sort can never grow faster than n^2, n^4, n^100, n^n.

Another point to keep in mind when describing Big O is thinking in terms of n getting arbitrarily large or going towards infinity. In this example n is 10, but when you consider the Big O of larger values of n in the worst-case the number of steps will increase, but will never exceed n^2. I hope this helps!